# Article page url in chinese language Drupal 7

Tags: views, database, hooks

When i am visiting my site individual article page url in chinese language got below error, even this URL working fine in my localhost.

Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE7:titl...' for column 'location' at row 1' in /var/www/includes/database/database.inc:2204     cloud-server-01     /zh-hans/articles/%E5%9D%90%E6%8B%A5%E5%95%

Answer (score 1):

This error might appear when the MySQL database is encoded as UTF8. In that case, Unicode characters represented with 4 bytes are not accepted. The accepted reply to the following StackOverflow question explains that the database needs to be encoded using the `utf8mb4` encoding and the `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957238/incorrect-string-value-when-trying-to-insert-utf-8-into-mysql-via-jdbc

A more complete explanation about the `utf8mb4` encoding on MySQL can be found here:

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

In case you need to re-encode your existing Drupal database, there is an experimental Drush command for it at [UTF8MB4 Convert](https://www.drupal.org/project/utf8mb4_convert).

Comment: The column's collation is utf8_general_ci.What could be the problem?

Comment: @Suraj I think the collation needs to be utf8mb4_unicode_ci instead. I have just edited my answer with some additional details.